# How to change the color of all Labels in a UIView in Swift?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I found a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25585543/how-to-change-the-text-color-of-all-text-in-uiview). But the problem is it is in **OBJ-C**. I do not know the code and am working in **SWIFT** so please can anyone explain and translate this code in swift. 
I am still new to swift so please help me.

Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create

```
var globalColor = UIColor.red

class CustomLbl:UILabel {
  override func awakeFromNib() {  // inside IB
    super.awakeFromNib()
    self.textColor = globalColor
  }
  override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) { // programmatically 
     super.draw(rect)
     self.textColor = globalColor
  }
}
```

And assign it in IB or code , for programmatically call

```
self.view.setNeedsDisplay()
```

after you change global color

Answer (score 1):

with an extension. Maybe its not the perfect solution but once you applied it to all needed labels, then it applies to all labels when you make a change. Create a new swift file and put the following code in:

```
    import UIKit

extension UILabel {
    func labelColor() {
        self.textColor = UIColor.red //or whichever color you want
    }
}
```

And in the viewDidLoad or viewWillLoad you can do:

```
yourLabel.labelColor()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
self.view.subviews.forEach { (view) in    // Loop
     if let label = view as? UILabel {    // check the type
          label.textColor = .red          // assign the color
     }
}
```

And `self` is your `viewController`

As explain in the similar question, you have to

> Loop through all the UIView's in self.view.subviews and check if it's
>   of type UILabel.

Comment: It only changes the color of labels directly under the ViewController, it does not change the color of the Labels inside another UIView in the ViewController. Is there a way to do so.

Comment: this should be a recursive process which isn't the good option here

Comment: You can loop the subviews to find another UILabel, but in your case I think the response of @Sh_Khan is better, you should create a custom UILabel class